# How would I print out the address like the Hexdump function in UNIX

Tags: c, hex, hexdump

There I have this assignment where I am suppose to emulate the hexdump function from unix. I got my program to dump files into hex but i am having trouble printing the offset and the printable characters.

Here is my code:

```
/*performs a hex and an octal dump of a file*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define LINESIZE 512

void hexdump(FILE *fp);
void octaldump(FILE *fp);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

   if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb+")) == '\0')
   {
    perror("fopen");
    return 0;
   }

   hexdump(fp);

   return 0;
}

void hexdump(FILE *fp)
{
   char temp [LINESIZE];
   size_t i = 0;
   size_t linecount = 1;
   long int address = 0;


   while(fscanf(fp," %[^\n] ", temp) == 1)
   {
     printf("%5d", address);

     for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
     {
        printf("%02x ", temp[i]);

        if(linecount == 16)
        {
            printf("\n");
            linecount = 0;          
        }
        linecount++;
     }
     printf(" | ");

     for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
     {
         if(temp[i] < 32)
         {
            printf(".");
         }
         else
         {
             printf("%c", temp[i]);
         }
     }
     printf("\n");
    }
}
```

As i said above, my program is suppose to print the offset then the hex value of the file padded with 0's, then the printable characters of the file like so.

```
0000000 7f 2a 34 f3 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | test file
```

I managed to print out the printable characters, but they appear after the hex part. So if one line of hexcode extends to the next line, it prints the printable characters on the nextline.

For example:

```
2a 3b 4d 3e 5f
12 43 23 43 | asfdg df
```

How do i get it to print whatever character appears after one line of the hex characters?

PS: For some reason my program doesn't pad 0's for some reason.

EDIT1: I got the offset part, i just keep adding 16 to my address variable and keep printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll just give you some pointers on how to approach your problem. I'll be as vague as I can so as to not interfere with your learning.

First of all, don't use [`fscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) if you're writing a hex dumper, use [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) instead. The `scanf` family of functions are meant for text and hex dumpers are usually used with binary data.

If you use `fread` and read just enough bytes at a time to fill one line of output, then you can produce your desired output with two `for` loops (one for hex, one for characters) followed by a single newline.

As far as your zero padding problem goes, read [the `printf` man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), your `"%5d"` format string needs a little bit more.

Comment: insteading of using fread, can i read it in character by character using fgetc then limit the number of chracters being put on screen?

Comment: @user830812: I suppose you could but I don't know why you would want to. You need a full line's worth of bytes before you can produce any output so why not `fread` 16 bytes at a time?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the sscanf part of the while loop with fread, but i don't think its going through the loop now

Comment: @user830812: Make sure you're checking for the right return value from `fread`.

Comment: i = fread(temp, sizeof(temp), 16, fp);
 
 printf("%d", i);

I've done that to check the return value apparently its zero, so my loop doesnt even go at all

Comment: @user830812: `fread(temp, 1, 16, fp)`, the second argument is the size of each item in your buffer (1 in this case as you're working with bytes).